# Scrollable two column layout based on gentelella

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, gentelella

I'm creating a layout based on https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella
I'm trying to make three column template with second column being scrollable.

This is mockup of layout.
[image]
basically, I need to create two panel inside

I tried min-height to 100% and overflow hidden on parent. right_col having overflow-y to scroll.

[image]
Here is the issue.
The second column looks to have scroll but still takes up the full length required to display content.

here is the my [code](http://pastebin.com/L4NKShEN)

Here is the my [css](http://pastebin.com/daZQX3Cd)

Comment: can you please share the css code too? That's where the real issue lies.

Comment: please see the attached css

Answer (score 0):

If you give the container element a height of 100vh, then you can give it's children 100% height.

vh is a measuring unit of the **viewport height** which can give you something to base subsequent relative measurements.

Your problem is that the scrollable element doesn't have the correct height.
Setting **max-height** or **height** will help the situation.

In this example, give all columns a min-height of 100%, but then give the column you want to scroll a max-height of 100% and scroll overflow-y e.g.

```css
.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  min-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 3em; /* This is just for the example, so we have enough stuff to scroll */
}
#column2 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="column" id="column1">
</div>
<div class="column" id="column2">
  content to be scrolled
  <br>content to be scrolled
  <br>content to be scrolled
  <br>content to be scrolled
  <br>content to be scrolled
  <br>content to be scrolled
  <br>content to be scrolled
  <br>content to be scrolled
  <br>content to be scrolled
  <br>content to be scrolled
  <br>content to be scrolled
  <br>content to be scrolled
  <br>content to be scrolled
  <br>
</div>
<div class="column" id="column3">
</div>
```

The key is defining the height of the element whose contents you wish to scroll.